# In Python, how do I iterate over the rows of a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, loops, sparse-matrix

This is what I am looking to do. x below is a sparse matrix.

```
for d in x:
    yvalue = foo(d[bf])
```

I consume yvalue afterward, just not pasting the code here. Assume that bf is computed somehow.

The above was my code for a dense matrix, but I need to find the equivalent code for a sparse matrix.

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: That rather depends on how you are storing the sparse matrix...

Comment: "Assume that bf is computed somehow" - so it's different for every row?

Comment: How is the sparse matrix coded?  Is it one you made yourself, or are you suing one of the `scipy.sparse` types?  Those classes have row access methods, which vary in speed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you do not want to use a `matrix` as the data structure of a sparse matrix. You may prefer `list of list`. This is more about algorithm and data structure than python.

Just like we use `incidence matrix` (2 dimensional array) to represent dense graph, but `adjacency list` (list of list) to represent sparse graph.

Comment: Na, this is a homework that requires me to use a sparse matrix. I don't have a choice, sorry.